# Absolute div's width becomes so small that the text is wrapping

Tags: html, css, width, css-position

When I make a button I want to make a div that appears when I hover the button, though I have problems with it's width and it's position.

The problem can be seen below in the pictures and in the jsfiddle. When I make something absolute to the relative button, it looks like it's max-width becomes the width of the button. If the button is small, the hover div will also be small. How can I make a normal hover div with a `width:auto`?

http://jsfiddle.net/ghpc9fwk/

[image: This maybe describes the problem a bit more]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a `white-space: nowrap;` attribute to prevent the text from wrapping on nearest occasions;)

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/1revewwm/

*I 've also modified the `bottom` attribute*

Comment: this doesn't work if you want to set a max-width

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for you but you could perhaps use `::before` pseudo element to achieve such layout.

```
.alt-test{    
    background-color:blue;    
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;    
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.alt-test::before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:-10px;    
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ghpc9fwk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="alt">Click here now!</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.button{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:red;
}
.alt{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: none;
    background-color:blue;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.button:hover .alt{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Gr/ghpc9fwk/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your button and alt container in another div with `position: relative;`. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mb38rj9u/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="alt">Click here now!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.button{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}

.alt{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    display: none;
}

.button:hover + .alt {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution as noted before is to add `white-space:nowrap` to your alt/caption div, so it stretches until you insert some `<br>`

#### Additionally

I would recommend you not to use

`bottom: -[something]px`

but to use

`top: 100%`.

this way the button could be of variable height.

I modified your JSFiddle accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/ghpc9fwk/3/